# Subversion: Tortoise+AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Open Ankh seems to be using Subversion 1.6.2 and Tortoise uses Subversion 1.6.0.

After creating a repository with Tortoise I could not get ankh to see it.

After downloading subversion and doing 
svn admin -create --pre-1.6-compatible z:\......\etc..
now ankh can see it. This is my first time using version control, and maybe I don't need tortoise, but the windows explorer integration sounds nice.

I'm using file:/// not an svnserve or apache.

am I going to be able to use tortoise along side ankh or will I continue to have problems or possibly corrupt the repository?

Comment: sorry this should read AnkhSvn seems to be using subversion 1.6.0, and tortoise seems to use Subversion 1.6.2. going to try a daily build of ankhSVN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problems but resolved them by installing latest (2.1 daily build) of AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 7):

As long as both tools are on the same major/minor version of Subversion (i.e. 1.6.any) then they should be able to work together.

Are you talking about AnkhSVN? If so, you might need to get a daily build, as their page mentions using the latest daily for Subversion 1.6 support.
http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

If you update one client but not another and there is a minor version difference (i.e. 1.6 vs. 1.5), then the newer client will update the working copy and you won't be able to work with it in the older client.

Comment: yes AnkhSvn, going to try a daily build to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The latest version of TortoiseSVN was built against SVN 1.6.2, get it [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads).  That may fix your problem.</strike>

The original poster corrected his post, and the above line no longer applies.

You should be able to use both side by side with no problems.  I was for a while, and did not encounter any issues

Comment: you said you were using both for awhile, did you change version control programs, or was using one of them sufficient to drop the other?

Comment: there were a couple reasons why I dropped use of Ankh: 1)it was an earlier version that did have the SCC support that the new one has, 2) it didnt work well with the ASP.NET Website project I was working on, 3) I just liked TortoiseSVN better, and lastly 4) I left the last employer, and my current employer has a much more stringent software guideline, so I would have to get Ankh approved.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing problems with Ankh, but after installing subversion 1.6.2 it works!!
So probably you need to update your subversion to 1.6.2

Comment: I actually did not need subversion installed to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

from http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads

**If some of the projects do not show glyphs**
 - Check if the projects are connected in **File -> Subversion -> Change Source Control**
Make sure that at least the Solution and the projects missing glyphs are connected
(Many project types do not require explicit binding)*